# pandas replace bytes object b'\x00' with string

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace, byte

I have a Dataframe with a column contains bytes objects `b'\x00'` to `b'\x08'`. I would like to replace them with the corresponding string `'00'` to `'08'`.

The bytes objects from `b'\x01'` to `b'\x08'` can be easily replaced by using a dict in `dataframe.replace`.

However the job on b'\x00' doesn't work. Here is my test.

My python version is

> '3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Nov  8 2017, 15:10:56) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'. Pandas is pre-installed.

```
bytes_list=[b'\x00',b'\x01',b'\x02',b'\x03',b'\x04',b'\x05',b'\x06',b'\x07',b'\x08']

bytes_df=pd.DataFrame({"bytes":bytes_list})

replacements = {b'\x00': '00',b'\x01': '01',b'\x02': '02',b'\x03': '03',b'\x04': '04'
               ,b'\x05': '05',b'\x06': '06',b'\x07': '07',b'\x08': '08'}

bytes_df.replace(replacements,inplace=True)

print(bytes_df)
```

Output:

```
      bytes
 0       b'\x00'
 1       01
 2       02
 3       03
 4       04
 5       05
 6       06
 7       07
 8       08
```

So you can see the bytes object `b'\x00'` isn't replaced.

Later I use applymap with a lambda func get what I need.

```
bytes_df.applymap(lambda x: x[0] if type(x) is bytes else x)
```

But I was still wondering if there is any other easy and pythonic way can do the same. And I was also wondering if this is a bug.

Could anyone explain?

Comment: \x00 is the "string terminator" for C strings. might be related.

Comment: Probably. After all, is Python written in C?

Comment: [one answer on: Why is Python written in C and not in C++](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/21011/286447)

Comment: You might also be able to incorporate the `'0'+str(ord(b'\x00'))` "trick" into some lambda and still use replace or other panda transform methods - not really firm in it

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could circumvent the problem:

```
import pandas as pd

bytes_list=[b'\x00',b'\x01',b'\x02',b'\x03',b'\x04',b'\x05',b'\x06',b'\x07',b'\x08']

bytes_df=pd.DataFrame({ "bytes": ['0'+str(ord(x)) for x in bytes_list] }) 

print(bytes_df)
```

Output:

```
  bytes
0    00
1    01
2    02
3    03
4    04
5    05
6    06
7    07
8    08
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, there are several way to make it. Pythonic! :)

Comment: Actually so far I can see two way to circumvent this issue: 1. x[0] when x is the bytes type. 2. ord() which can get the order number. When you deal with MySQL bit() type field, it will be useful.